# Backbone update model multiple times

Tags: jquery, templates, backbone.js

I have a simple backbone app called from other app. 
It's seems a dialog box to view message like "Welcome user" or "update succesfull".
I have created this app and when I call it the first time all variable is set: title and message but when I call it the second, third times value aren't updated but in console I see the variable change!
This is my view  simplified I pass to it same value

```
var StatusMessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : tmplStatusMessage,
    model : new StatusMessageModel(),
    initialize : function (data) {
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        this.model.set(data);
    },
    render : function () {
        console.log("View - StatusMessage.render msg: " + this.model.get('message'));
        var template = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
        var html = template(this.model.toJSON());

        //-----------INTO THIS CONSOLE LOG I SEE HTML UPDATED!!! WHY???
        console.log('HTML: ' + html);

        if($("#status-message").length === 0) {
            $("body").append(html);
        }

            //AFTER A DELAY I CLOSE THE APP 
        var self = this;
        var intro_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#status-message").addClass("enter");

            var outro_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                self.closeMessage();
            }, 5000);
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

To update into another view I use this code for exampl and the message is good if I trace it into the console:

```
statusMessageView.model.set({
    title : title,
    message : msg
});
```

Why the html is updated, variable is updated in console log but not into the template I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `#status-message` element which is overwritten the first time only, to avoid this problem you could try something like this:

```
render : function () {
    console.log("View - StatusMessage.render msg: " + this.model.get('message'));
    var template = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
    var html = template(this.model.toJSON());



    if($("#status-message").length === 0) {
        $("body").append('<div id="status-message"></div>');
    }

    $("#status-message").html(html);

    var self = this;
    var intro_timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#status-message").addClass("enter");

        var outro_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            self.closeMessage();
        }, 5000);
    }, 500);
}
```

In this way, your app should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing that seems likely to cause initialize/render call number 1 to work and subsequent calls to do nothing is this:

```
if($("#status-message").length === 0) {
    $("body").append(html);
}
```

To quickly "fix" this you could do:

```
this.$el.html(html);
if($("#status-message").length === 0) {
    $("body").append(this.el);
}
```